OAuth scope required to delete a (starred repos) list in GitHub
I want to programmatically delete all the lists I have created in GitHub. Basically, these:

But I'm getting the error "-username- does not have the correct permissions to execute DeleteUserList".
I'm using a private GitHub App (with all the permissions included). I'm following the device auth flow since I have nodejs (actually, bun) scripts. I'm using 'repo, public_repo, user' as the scope but I cannot find any documentation that lists down the permissions required for each mutation.
My deleteUserList call looks like this:
  await graphql(
    `
mutation deleteList($id: ID!) {
  deleteUserList(input: {listId: $id}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
`,
    {
      headers: {
        authorization: `token ${token}`,
      },
      id: list.id,
    },
  );

This graphql worked in the explorer and successfully deleted one list. (I guess I should have deleted these lists manually but man, the urge to automate things! So here I am.)
Any help is appreciated.
